# Angular 5, TypeScript observable issue

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Trying to get a messaging app to work, but I cannot seem to get past an TS error.

The Editor syntax checker - shows this error
Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'MessageThread[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

the CODE

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

import { MessageThread } from './message-thread.model';

@Injectable()
export class MessageThreadService {

    private getMessageThreadsUrl = 'api/message-thread/get';  // URL to web API
    private postMessageThreadsUrl = 'api/message-thread/post';  // URL to web API

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private socket;
    private url = window.location.origin;

    /*
    * Get MessageThreads from server
    */
    getMessageThreads(): Observable<MessageThread[]> {
        const observable = new Observable(observer => {
            console.log('Socket:', this.url);
            this.socket = io(this.url);
            this.socket.on('refreshMessageThreads', (data) => {
                observer.next(data);
            });

            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            };
        });

        return observable; // **** THIS LINE SHOWS ERROR ****
    }

...
```

the angular transpiler throws this error

ERROR in src/app/components/messages/message-thread.service.ts(35,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'MessageThread[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

Tee Message Thread Model looks like this:

```
export class MessageThread {
    constructor(
        public messageThread: string
    ) { }

}
```

help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You aren't providing the generic type for the observable anywhere, so it defaults to `{}`, which isn't an array of message threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the issue is this part of the error:

> Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'MessageThread[]'.

When you make an instance of a class that requires a generic, TypeScript will default that generic to `{}` when it can't be inferred elsewhere. In this case, these two are the same:

```
const observable = new Observable(observer => {
const observable = new Observable<{}>(observer => {
```

Then, it complains when you try to return `Observable<{}>` to a function typed to return `Observable<MessageThread[]>`. The solution is to specify the generic yourself:

```
const observable = new Observable<MessageThread[]>(observer => {
```